# Difference between module and closure

Tags: javascript

I am not experienced with javascript. I am wondering what's the difference between **closure** and **module**? Can anyone explain to me with a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: [Closure for Dummies](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html)

A module is just a class that can stand by its own.And can be combined with other classes.

Comment: +1 However, a module might not even be a class. It's just a collection of "things" (usually objects/methods, but could be loose functions, constants, etc) bundled together, often as as single .js file.